# If condition always return false (elipsis)

Tags: javascript, multithreading, concurrency, elips-studio

I am quite new to elipsis but the following returns true even when I assign the variable as false.

PS: Notice the iff condition.

```
import system.obj.* from elipsis.system;

iff(elem in system.obj.elem) {
  println('in true')
}
```

Comment: What is an `iff` condition ? Just curious. Most likely a typo but it does appear more than once.

Comment: Hi, How is my asnwer doing? Is a bit selfish to ask a question, receive help and not give feedback...

Answer (score 1):

the `in` keyword checks that the object contains the property mentioned. You are asking for the property inside the property.

You should actually ask the object for the property, like this:

```
iff(elem in system.obj) {
  println('in true')
}
```

By the way, the `in` keyword don't checks the value, just if the property exists. Setting a property to `false` will make it to exist but with the value `false`, so it will always return `true`.

To remove a property in JavaScript you must use the `delete` keyword:

```
system.obj.elem = true;

iff(elem in system.obj) {
  println('in exists'); // CODE REACHED
}

system.obj.elem = false;

iff(elem in system.obj) {
  println('in exists'); // CODE REACHED
}

delete system.obj.elem;

iff(elem in system.obj) {
  println('in exists'); // CODE NOT REACHED
}
```

I don't know if the `iff` is actually real code and you have some kind of transpiler or is a typo. In JavaScript it do not exists. Have searched a bit on Internet and I think is a typo.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
import system.obj.* from elipsis.system;

iff(elem in system.obj) {   println('in true') }
```